# Why can't it resolve the method?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a constructor with 2 string arrays, but it says that it can't resolve the method.

I'm trying to make a customlistadapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final String[] søgeord;
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] søgeord) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname, søgeord); //it can't resolve this

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.søgeord=søgeord;
}
```

This is only the relevant code. However, I can't really see why it gives me this error: `Cannot resolve method 'super(android.app.Activity, int, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[])`

I need it to contain an activity, 2 string arrays and an integer array

**EDIT**
This is my new `CustomListAdapter` class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Container>{

private final Activity context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, Container[] containers) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, containers);
        this.context=context;
    }
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Container c = new Container();

    txtTitle.setText(c.itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(c.imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText(c.itemname[position]);
    return view;

 };
}
```

This is the OnCreate method:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    final String[] søgestreng = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("søg");


    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, Container[] containers); //this is wrong, why?

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html there is no arrayadapter constructor with parameters you are sending so that it returns error.

Comment: Ok, what can I do to solve it? I really need "søgeord". I know I can delete it and it'll fix the problem, but I need it.

Comment: You can use BaseAdapter instead.

Comment: `Container c = getItem(position);` instead of `Container c = new Container();` that is just the way the ArrayAdapter works.

Comment: Ok, when I wanna use it in another class in the OnCreate method what do I write? I'm sending data from class to another, so I also need the input in the in the CustomListAdapter as well. What should I write instead of `listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, Container[] containers, sogestreng);` ? sogestreng is an string array `final String[] søgestreng = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("søg");`

Comment: @leoderprofi : have uploaded the  `OnCreate` method

Comment: look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: also I believe your initial question is answered. Please mark as accepted and create a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your data into containers and create a List of these containers which you then feed into the ArrayAdapter

```
String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] søgeord
```

fits into

```
public class Container{
    public final String søgeord;
    public final String itemname;
    public final Integer imgid;
    Container(String søgeord, String itemname, Integer imgid){
        this.søgeord=søgeord;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.imgid = imgid;
    }
}
```

and becomes

```
Container[] containers;
```

and can then be feed into the super constructor

```
super(context, R.layout.mylist, containers);
```

This way there can not be a mismatch between the sizes of all your arrays.

All in all:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Container>

private final Activity context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, Container[] containers) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, containers); 
    this.context=context;
}
```

then you can access the data in `getView` like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Container currentItem = getItem(position);
    ...
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Where do I write `String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] søgeord` ?

Comment: When I wanna use it in getview, why can't I write `Container c = new Container();` and use `c.itemname[position]`? Have uploaded my getview

Comment: you don't have three arrays, just one but every entry contains three things. And how should `Container c = new Container()` yield any item you want? that creates an empty container. :S You have to use `getItem()` to get the item associated to the view.

Comment: So `txtTitle.setText(currentItem.itemname)` ?